# How to speed up panda?

Tags: tools

When looking for a reversing tool I discovered [PANDA](https://github.com/panda-re/panda). Unfortunately, its performance is too slow. When I run some large programs in a virtual machine, the whole system becomes very slow and I can't debug the programs at all. Are there other faster full system debuggers that support taint forward or backward analysis?